# vertx Python can't set_expect_multipart in post request handler

Tags: python, vert.x

I am using `vertx 2.1.5 (built 2014-11-13 15:15:56)` and Python api.

My code is about handle a post request and get form attributes. But it not working.

```
import vertx
from core.http import RouteMatcher

logger = vertx.logger()

rm = RouteMatcher()


def auctions_handler(req):
    req.set_expect_multipart(True)

    @req.end_handler
    def end_handler():
        print 'multi part %s' % req.is_expect_multipart()
        attrs = req.form_attributes()
        print attrs


rm.all_re("/auction/", auctions_handler)

vertx.create_http_server().request_handler(rm).listen(8080)
```

Error

```
multi part True
Exception in Python verticle
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call expectMultiPart(true) before request body is received to receive form attributes
    at org.vertx.java.core.http.impl.DefaultHttpServerRequest.formAttributes(DefaultHttpServerRequest.java:251)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

So how to fix that? Is that the bug of vertx python api? Do I switch to Java?